# AWS Speed , transfer a file from S3 to Ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

is there any benchmark of how long it takes to transfer a 1GB, 5GB, 10GB file from S3 bucket to EC2 volume in AWS (Same Geo, Same A-z)

We are experimenting with backup/restore and these benchmarks are needed for planning

Comment: I don't think there is and I also don't think this question should be on SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found [this](http://blog.takipi.com/amazon-ec2-2015-benchmark-testing-speeds-between-aws-ec2-and-s3-regions/) 2015 benchmark and [this](http://www.rightscale.com/blog/cloud-industry-insights/network-performance-within-amazon-ec2-and-amazon-s3) network performance experiment.

I think it can be summed up to this:

[image]

BTW, I also don't think this question belongs to SO.

** Average upload time of 10MB in seconds from EC2 server locations to S3 locations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this info!